# Load ContentValues into a ListView Using a Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

I am trying load `ContentValues` into a `ListView` using a custom adapter shown below.

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private Activity activity;
  private ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

  public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ContentValues v) {
    activity = a;
    values = v;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if(convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_name);
    TextView reg_no. = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_reg_no);
    ImageView image_thumb = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id._list_item_image);
    ContentValues student = new ContentValues();

    /** here I am trying to get a single student data from the ContentValues **/
    student = values.get(position); //Getting the error on this line 

   //Setting values into the ListView
    name.setText(variant.getAsString(StudenttContract.Column.NAME));
    reg_no.setText(variant.getAsString(StudentContract.Column.REG_NO));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(variant.getAsString(StudentContract.Column.thumb_url), image_thumb);
    return vi;
}
```

The problem is that i get an error: `The method get(String) in the type ContentValues is not applicable for the arguments (int)` on this line:

```
    student = values.get(position);
```

How can i resolve this or what else can i do to get the data of one student from the `ContentValues`.

Comment: can you include ContentValues class

Comment: @erik the `ContentValues` class is imported from `android.content.ContentValues`

Comment: well then, get only takes a string there.. I am thinking you want to create a Student Data Model Class and instead of ContentValues, make an ArrayList<Student>

Comment: @erik Thank you very much an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` solved my problem.